# Sending an SSH comand with JSCH to Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ssh, jsch

I want to write an app for sending an SSH command to my Raspberry Pi with my smartphone. I read that JSCH is a good choice, so I included the JSCH Library to my project in Eclipse.

I created a new class named `SSH.java` and put this code in:

```
package com.app.bondrucker;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;


public class SSH {
    public static String executeRemoteCommand() throws Exception {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession("pi", "192.168.2.10", 22);
        session.setPassword("raspberry");


        // Avoid asking for key confirmation
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(prop);

        session.connect();

        // SSH Channel
        ChannelExec channelssh = (ChannelExec)
        session.openChannel("exec");
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        channelssh.setOutputStream(baos);

        // Execute command
        channelssh.setCommand("sudo shutdown -h now");
        channelssh.connect();
        channelssh.disconnect();

        return baos.toString();
    }
}
```

Could you please check my code?

The App crashes when this line gets executed:

```
session.connect();
```

I start the JSCH-code with a button, which is executing this code:

```
SSH.executeRemoteCommand();
```

Here are the LogCat messages which appear when I press the button (to execute the SSH comand):

08-04 22:00:38.668: D/libc(29531): [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 12(0x3139322e313638),sn(),family 0,flags 4
08-04 22:00:38.668: D/libc(29531): [NET] getaddrinfo-, SUCCESS
08-04 22:00:38.668: W/dalvikvm(29531): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d4be18)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/ActivityManager(755): App crashed! Process: com.app.bondrucker
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531): Process: com.app.bondrucker, PID: 29531
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3865)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4480)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18686)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3860)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    ... 11 more
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531): Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:349)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:215)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at com.app.bondrucker.SSH.executeRemoteCommand(SSH.java:30)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at com.app.bondrucker.MainActivity.selfDestruct(MainActivity.java:42)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    ... 14 more
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531): Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:576)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:201)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:590)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:128)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:178)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:150)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:343)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    ... 18 more
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:181)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:561)
08-04 22:00:38.678: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):    ... 24 more
08-04 22:00:38.678: W/ActivityManager(755):   Force finishing activity com.app.bondrucker/.MainActivity

Comment: do you have a stacktrace? I've made an app that uses Jsch to ssh to raspberry pi

Comment: how can i get the stackstrace?

Comment: in your Logcat in Eclipse

Comment: I expect it will be throwing a NetworkOnMainThreadException. You should investigate how to avoid this by using an AsyncTask.

Comment: I edited my question and put the LogCat messages in, because I was not able to answer my own question.

Comment: In the Tab "Session.class" the line "this.password=null" gets tagged.